# Elegant way to get ExternalInterface working with all browsers

Tags: javascript, html, flash, externalinterface

I want to call a function inside a Flash movie from javascript, using the `ExternalInterface` class. The problem is that to get it to work with Firefox I need to use the `embed` element and with the rest I have to get the `object` element. To solve it, I gave different ids to that two elements and depending on the user agent I select one or the other:

```
 function getMovie(movieName) {

    alert(navigator.userAgent);
     if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
         return document["flash_embed"];
     } else {
         return document["flash_object"];
     }
 }
```

This works, but it is not very elegant and it may not work with other browsers... Do you know a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed your flash movie, and then use it to retrieve the correct id.

Comment: any specific reason to do so?

Comment: A coworker doesn't want to add the full script just to do this.